# Django rest framework - Optimizng serialization of nested related field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Given the following models:

```
class Model_A:
    ...

class Model_B:
    ...

class Model_C:
    model_a = ForeignKey(Model_A, related_name='c_items')
    model_b = ForeignKey(Model_B)
    ...
```

And the following model serializers setup:

```
class Model_A_Serializer:
    class Model_C_Serializer:
        class Meta:
            model = Model_C
            fields = ( 'model_b', ... )

    c_items = Model_C_Serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ( 'c_items', ... )
```

And a basic vieweset:

```
class Model_A_Viewset:
    model = Model_A
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Model_A_Serializer

    ...
```

When the user POST's the following JSON payload to create an instance of Model_A along with instances of Model_C:

```
{
    'c_items': [
        {
            'model_b': 1
        },
        {
            'model_b': 2
        },
        {
            'model_b': 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: Model_B instances with IDs 1, 2, and 3 already exist, but no Model_A and no Model_C instances exist in the above example.

Then I noticed that django seems to execute the following queries when serializing the incoming data:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM Model_B WHERE id = 1;
SELECT ... FROM Model_B WHERE id = 2;
SELECT ... FROM Model_B WHERE id = 3;
```

This seems unnecessary to me as a single `SELECT ... FROM Model_B WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` would do the job.

How do I go about optimizng this?

I have tried to modify the queryset in the viewset above like so:

```
queryset = model.objects.prefetch_related('c_items__model_b').all()
```

But this did not make a difference in the number of queries being executed.

Answer (score 0):

been a while since I django'd but I'm pretty sure you need to prefetch the relations and the relations relations, and I'm pretty sure prefetch is for many to many or reverse foreign keys, while select is for direct foreign keys, which means you can save one query by using select_related instead:

```
model.objects.prefetch_related('c_items').select_related('c_items__model_b').all()
```

Comment: I am assuming this is for the queryset in the viewset. I added this and it throws an error `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'c_items'. Choices are: ...`.

Comment: Choices are the other related fields in Model_A to which the model has a direct foreign key reference to.